# How do a make one form stay on top of another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have found the `Form.TopMost` property but it puts the form on top of everything, including stuff that isn't part of my app. I've got a suspicion that I'm missing something obvious here. (Is `Form` the proper bases class for a non modal dialog box?)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the Form.Owner property of your dialog form and set it to the main Form.

Read more here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx

The Owned form will never be displayed behind the Owner Form.

Comment: Is there a way to make the owner form inoperable until its owned form is dismissed?

Answer (score 11):

It is very simple; You just have to pass the owner when you call the `Show()` method

```
YourForm.Show(parentForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify parent-child relationships between windows by supplying the parent Form as parameter to the ShowDialog() method called on the child Form. The child window will then stay on top of the parent and also minimize and restore along with the parent.

Comment: I can't use ShowDialog as that makes it modal.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly your opening a form from your application, and you want your new form to be on top of the old one.

To do this you can use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) and [StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx)

```
SomeForm MyNewForm = new SomeForm();
MyNewForm.ShowDialog();
```

this will make that form stay on top of the orignal one, and you can also use

```
MyNewForm .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

To control where that new form shows on the screen.

Comment: I can't use ShowDialog as that makes it modal.