# System.Windows.Window.Show() launching in background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom Window derived from System.Windows.Window.
However, launching this custom window makes it in the background to the parent window.

```
public partial class MyForm : System.Windows.Window
{
}

            var form = new MyForm();
            form.Show();
```

What properties shall i set to make it always appear in the foreground?
I'm pretty new to Winforms so any help is much appreciated.

Based on the suggestions i tried setting the form owner.
However, the parent is a user control whereas the 'Owner' property is a 'Window'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do a make one form stay on top of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121209/how-do-a-make-one-form-stay-on-top-of-another)

Comment: See my edit pls

Comment: Are you looking for `form.TopMost = true` or `form.Activate()`? 

Comment: Neither of these! If you see my question carefully, form 'Window' is launched and goes to the backgroud

Comment: How you get System.Windows.Window in winform application ?

Answer (score -1):

make sure form visibility is true.

```
var form = new MyForm();
form.visible=true;
form.Show();
```

Comment: This did not work. I did Visibility = Visibility.Visible.